# Looking for a horizontal image scroller/gallery plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, slider, gallery

I'm looking for a plugin to beautifully showcase some work. 
I'm looking for something like the free [wp Image horizontal reel scroll slideshow](http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2011/05/08/wordpress-plugin-image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/#.UTdyraVqvZg). 
It does not have to be a free plugin.

Do you have any suggestion for a horizontal image scroller/gallery plugin for WordPress

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather vague / opion question, but let's see...

If you're looking for a premium slider, you can check out [Soliquoy](http://soliloquywp.com/), [SliderPRO](http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-pro-wordpress-premium-slider-plugin/253501), and [Royal Slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/royalslider-touch-content-slider-for-wordpress/700256). You can read a [review and comparison](http://chrislema.com/comparing-premium-sliders-for-wordpress-by-performance/) of these on Chris Lema's blog.

I would also recommend checking out [FlexSlider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) from WooThemes, and [Meteor Slides](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/meteor-slides/).

There are countless sliders and plugins out there. You'll have to do some research and see which one best suits your needs. I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer, but none of those sliders that you mentioned really works for my client, if you go to www.gomedia.us and see their front page slider you will understand what I'm looking for.. I want to be able to showcase thumbs or small images in like a scroll mode..